# How do I put a comma into an integer input?

Tags: python, datetime, time, traceback

So, I'm making a program that uses datetime. When I try and use the input command to enter the time for datetime whenever I run it it gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\461gdc15\OneDrive\Alarm.py", line 10, in <module>
start = datetime.time(input())
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

So, what I'm *trying* to do is add a comma to make it go off at a time in between two hours. Does anyone have any suggestions as of how to add a comma into an integer input?
I've been asked to add the Error Traceback. I think this is it.

Comment: Can you update your question with some example inputs and the corresponding values that `start` should have in each case?

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve], but you used `intput()` rather than `int(input())`.

Comment: Whenever I use `int(input())` it gives me
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\461gdc15\OneDrive\Alarm.py", line 10, in <module>start = datetime.time(int(input()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2, 50'`

Comment: It isn't clear what integer you expect `'2,30'` to represent.

Comment: So, in the module  `datetime` you insert the time, in this case it's 2:30 and the program has you type `2, 30`, into the `end = datetime.time()` area, but when I use `int(input())` it gives me the whole `ValueError` deal. When I use regular `input()` it gives me a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: you cannot.
An integer is just a number. Whenever you add another character, that becomes a string. Actually, the input function returns always a string, by default.
What you can do is use the str.split(",") method to split your string between commas, creating a list of those elements and then convert each value singularly into an integer, and finally giving it to your datetime.time() function call.

```
time_input = input("Insert your time. (Format: year, month, day)")
time_input = time_input.split(",")

start = datetime.time(int(time_input[0]), int(time_input[1]), int(time_input[2]))
```

Comment: So, how would I make the three `time_input`s into just two values? Like, Hour and Minute?

Comment: In that case you would need to specify the different format inside the input function and then just use the indexes [0] and [1] inside the datetime.time function since you only have two elements now. It's the same but just with two parameters this time, you don't need the time_input[2] anymore

Comment: Oh, I see, so I would type `2 30` without the comma?

Comment: No, you always need the comma in the input because that's the value you're gonna split for

Comment: You would type 2,30 in the input, split the input and then type datetime.time(int(time_input[0]), int(time_input[1]))

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import time
import winsound
now = datetime.datetime.now()
Current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
print("When do you want your alarm to go off? ")
time_input = input("Insert your time. (Format: Hour, Minute)")
end_time_input = input("If you don't turn it off when it goes off, when do you want it to stop? ")
time_input = time_input.split(",")
end_time_input = end_time_input.split(",")
start = datetime.time(*[int(x) for x in input().split(',')])
end = datetime.time(*[int(x) for x in input().split(',')])
while start <= now.time() <= end:
    if now.time() <= datetime.time(11, 59, 59):
        print("It is currently", now.time(), "AM.")
    elif now.time() >= datetime.time(11, 59, 59):
        print("It is currently", now.time(), "PM.")
winsound.PlaySound("C:/Music/Song")
##The path for my music ^^^ is too long for StackOverflow
```

I used the `(*[int(x) for x in input().split(',')])` thing and now the code just stops after the prompt....vvv

```
##When do you want your alarm to go off? 
##Insert your time. (Format: Hour, Minute)8, 50, 30
##If you don't turn it off when it goes off, when do you want it to stop? 9, 00, 00
```

This is what it gives me now, and I've waited through the time and nothing happens.
Side note... Also added a way for the alarm clock to tell whether it's morning or afternoon.

Comment: And if you want, I can share the file so you can edit it yourself and see it first hand. I recommend using Visual Studio Code as it is the program I am using. Just so we are on the same screen and you can see what I'm seeing.

Comment: And here's the PyDocs site in case you don't know what something is.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Your while loop only keeps the script going when the time is between the start and end. If you start your script outside of start and end, the whole loop won't execute and your script will go past it and end. You need to loop either way and beep only if it is the right time

Comment: So also do something like this?

Comment: New code somewhere here, it keeps changing position.

Comment: you should remove your answer to yourself and edit your question to make the code stay in one place.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import datetime, time, winsound, threading

print("When do you want your alarm to go off? ")
start = datetime.time(*[int(x) for x in input('Insert your time. (Format: Hour, Minute)\n > ').split(',')])
end = datetime.time(*[int(x) for x in input("If you don't turn it off when it goes off, when do you want it 
to stop?\n > ").split(',')])

while True:
    now = datetime.now().time()
    if start <= now <= end:
        print("It is currently", now.strftime('%I:%M %p'))
        t = threading.Thread(target=winsound.PlaySound, args=["C:/Music/Song",0])
        t.start()
        t.join()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The * means take the list and use each element as if it were a separate input into the time function. This takes the input string, splits it by comma and converts each resulting piece to an integer (instead of string).

Using a thread like this basically pauses the script until the sound is done playing.

Comment: So, just replace the `start` line with this and it'll work?

Comment: It will do what I think you were trying to make it do. So if you type into the prompt " 5, 30, 20", it will create a time object with 5 hours, 30 minutes, 20 seconds.

Comment: And I just paste it as is?

Comment: And do I replace the `end` too?

Comment: I edited my comment based on the additional code you posted. My method will work if the user provides hour,minute or hour,minute,second (or even just hour).

Comment: @GabeCodes I think my answer does exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, I put in the time and it's just sitting. Is it just waiting for that time to be true?

Comment: NVM, it worked now I just gotta put in a flag for winsound so it'll play. Where would I put extra input like this in this format?

Comment: @GabeCodes My answer starts a thread that should play the sound. The main thread waits until the child thread is terminated before continuing. This should prevent the situation of you having a main thread repeatedly trying to play the sound every millisecond every iteration in a loop. I don't think you need a flag.

Comment: It gives me 
 ` File"C:\Users\461gdc15\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: PlaySound() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)`

Comment: Ok, Big News! I got it working, but now I just gotta get it to loop

Comment: Basically instead of the `winsound.PlaySound("Path")` thing, you put that into a variable and name it like, Song1, or whatever. Then, in the `target=` bit, call the variable(`Song1` in my case,) and it will play the song, with that you can add whatever flags you would like to the `PlaySound` function, i.e. `Song1=winsound.PlaySound("Your/Path/Here", winsound.FLAG)`
`t=threading.Thread(target=Song1)`

Comment: @GabeCodes added a zero to arga for flags. Looking at the documentation one of the flags is ASYNC, implying that if that flag is not specified then the call is blocking. So maybe the threading is not necessary. What do you mean by looping? You want the sound to loop?

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to add the `winsound.SND_NOSTOP` flag to the line inside the args. Turns out I was messing it up with the variable. Thanks so much for the help.